# Function returns row type as single value instead of one value per field

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sql-function, set-returning-functions

The only time I encountered a similar problem on SO is on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690411/postgresql-psycopg2-returns-a-tuple-of-strings-instead-of-tuple-of-tuples), but the proposed solution was not relevant for me.

I call a PostgreSQL function, but it's returning a single value instead of one value per field, which I can access. I have a table `"Words"`, which consists of a primary key `word` and other fields.

This is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION equal(s TEXT) 
RETURNS "Word" AS $$
    SELECT *
    FROM "Word"
    WHERE word = s;
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

And this is the function call (using SQLAlchemy):

```
result = db.session.query(func.equal("is")).first()
```

Output would be: `'(is, ... )'` instead of the desired output: `('is', ...)`.

How can I adjust the function so it returns the tuple instead?

#### Follow-up question

As suggested, `db.session.execute(f"SELECT * FROM equal('{w}');").first()` does the trick. Unfortunately it returns a list of `None`'s if no result is found. I'd like it to return `None` instead. The `query` object in my original approach does this, but returns the output as a string.

Comment: The doc says: `For all other PostgreSQL return types, the returned Python value is converted to a string using the Python builtin str, and the result is passed to the input function of the PostgreSQL data type.` which might imply this is as per intended, but I'm still not sure how I can convert the string to a useable tuple. `eval()` marks it as a syntactically-invalid tuple because of the first string (in this case "is").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the function *call*, not the function.

To decompose the returned (composite) row type and get individual columns, call the function with:

```
SELECT * FROM equal('is');
```

instead of:

```
SELECT equal('is');
```

See:

- [Simple PostgreSQL function to return rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178470/simple-postgresql-function-to-return-rows/14185387#14185387)

To return nothing instead of a row of NULL values when no row is found, make it a set-returning function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION equal(_s text) 
  RETURNS SETOF "Word"  -- !
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
   SELECT *
   FROM   "Word"
   WHERE   word = _s;
$$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0057c09c200cb8bea61c2d6e81eb61e4)*

Same call.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)

> The `SETOF` modifier indicates that the function will return a set of items, rather than a single item.

So it can also return an *empty* set, i.e. nothing.

Comment: How can I achieve the same result using `db.session.query( ... )`?

Comment: @drew181: My expertise is with Postgres, not so much with SQL Alchemy. Should be simple, though. Treat it like any other query returning multiple columns.

Comment: `db.session.execute(f"SELECT * FROM equal('{w}');").first()` does the trick, unfortunately it returns a list of `None`'s if no result is found. I'd like it to return `None` instead. The `Query` object in my original approach does this, but returns the output as a string.

Comment: @drew181: I added a solution for that, too.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I adjusted the function as suggested and called it as follows `result = db.session.execute(f"SELECT * FROM equal('{w}');").fetchall()`.